# References on nonnegative matrices

Tags: matrices, reference-request, book-recommendation, nonnegative-matrices

I just started researching on non-negative matrices and their properties. Any suggestions on papers or sources for the theory and applications (ideally recent ones) of such matrices?

I am currently reading Berman's *Nonnegative matrices in the Mathematical History*, and R.B Bapat *Nonnegative matrices and Application*.

Comment: Please provide full references with DOI links.